# Assign new products to all the available pricebook using trigger

Tags: apex, before-trigger, after-trigger

i have a requirement that, if i insert new product then the newly created product must associate to all the pricebooks(including std and custom) but i get and error as illegal assignment from list to string i have tried the below code.

```
String pricebkId= [SELECT id,isStandard from Pricebook2];
List<PricebookEntry> pbeList = new List<PricebookEntry>();
for(Product2 p:  Trigger.New){
    pbeList.add(new PricebookEntry(
                    UnitPrice = 10, 
                    Pricebook2Id = pricebkId, 
                    product2Id = p.Id,
                    isActive = true));
}

insert pbeList;
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Vishal, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask], then **[edit]** your post to include the *exact* error message ***verbatim***, as well as a specific question (even if it's just *"How do I fix this error?"*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is returning a list of Price Books, not just a single one. So that's why you're getting that error. You'll also need to compensate for that by adding another loop below, so you'll need something like the below:

```
// Standard Price book must be first
List<PriceBook2> priceBooks = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 ORDER BY IsStandard DESC]; 
List<PricebookEntry> pbeList = new List<PricebookEntry>();
for(Product2 p:  Trigger.New){
    for (PriceBook2 priceBook : priceBooks) {
        pbeList.add(new PricebookEntry(
                        UnitPrice = 10, 
                        Pricebook2Id = priceBook.Id, 
                        product2Id = p.Id,
                        isActive = true));
    }
}

insert pbeList;
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas thats correct what you said but since i want to avoid inner for loops so  how to achieve that?

Comment: @VishalJ You can't, both loops are required.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for the answer but i am getting an error as STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED for the product.

Comment: @VishalJ The first price you specify must use the standard price book. Change your query to: `SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 ORDER BY IsStandard DESC` to make sure the standard price book occurs first.

Comment: @sfdcfox Good callout. I forgot about the ordering.

Comment: @sfdxfox thanks for your valuable update and since we cannot avoid inner for loop then it is working fine. if we could have avoided inner for loop then it would be more helpful as it is against best practices of salesforce.

Comment: @VishalJ Inner loops are not against best practices, in general. It's often better to avoid them if possible, but sometimes they're just necessary.

Comment: @nicholassavini got your point and thank you so much for your answer.